# Update App Hidden from the App Drawer in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

So i have a problem , in my App Manifest , i have removed this :

```
<intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

beacause my App is Hidden , Now , when i release a new Version , i noticed Google Play does no ask for Update , there just a 'Unistall' Button , it is beacause i have Removed the Intent Filter ? , Version Code and Name are Ok ,

Thanks .

Comment: Why do you removed that. Hope, Thats not the right solution.That statement determines the launcher activity in your application.

Comment: beacause , i needed to do it